# Existing Xcode git repo transferring to GitLab

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, gitlab, repository

How can you add an existing Xcode git repository to Gitlab, so you have the project on their site, too, without having to delete the Xcode project and init an git repo on gitlab first.

Couldn't find a build-in tool in Xcode, neither in GitLab.

Comment: Did you try to initialize in GITLab a new project and check the existing project out to it from Xcode. Or is that something you don't want?

Comment: not quiet sure what you meant but created a blank project again without a README.md and this time the instructions work.

Comment: That is the way I usually do that... ok. so it is solved?